# If else statement + AND OR in django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

**Hello Awesome People!**

Such a simple question, in python I can handle `if` `else` statement well, make it explicitly understandable by adding expressions inside parentheses like the following:

```
if ((user.is_active and user.is_administrator) or user.is_superuser) or (user.group.is_active and user.group.is_safe):
```

Parentheses are important to let python understands what this means. *This is just an example*, I know that I could do it another way, but what I want to know is, if **is it possible to have `AND` and `OR` combined in a long `if else` statement in template?**

```
{% if user.is_active and user.is_administrator or user.is_superuser or user.group.is_active and user.group.is_safe %}

{% endif %}
```

Obviously Django will render this not the way I expect.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The 'proper' way of doing that type of thing would be to pass a simple variable in the context rather than include logic in your template. Simple logic in templates is often required, but anything complex should be handled by a view. In terms of using `AND` & `OR` in templates though, have a look at this; https://stackoverflow.com/a/19284388/1199464

Comment: I totally understand, sometimes all the logic must be done in template (Imagine that I have CRUD buttons in templates, and some users have access to some actions). the pointed answer is a good one. thanks